# How can I insert HTML widget objects (Leaflet map or HTML table) in an HTML markdown document?

Tags: r, leaflet, r-markdown

I have tried a number of things including print(leafletMap) and just calling the object itself. Is there a specific function that I am to wrap my object in in order to get it to render in the document?

Answer (score 1):

if you use Rstudio create a RMarkdown File or RHMTL file then include into a chunk code like this (you will need package knitr to convert into hmtl)

````
```{r setup, include=TRUE}

library(leaflet)
m<-leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup="The birthplace of R")

m
```
````

otherwise you can save like an html document with the following code
like suggested in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/31642030/7600734

```
library(htmlwidgets)
saveWidget(m, file="m.html")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to this problem here, thanks to Jonathan: [How to use objects from global environment in Rstudio Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029611/how-to-use-objects-from-global-environment-in-rstudio-markdown)

The issue is that R Markdown requires the objects being rendered to be produced inside the code chunk, i.e. being produced every time you knit your document. *The makers of R Markdown did this intentionally to maximize the reproducibility of reports* (which I can appreciate!). A new, "invisible" environment is created and used every time you knit a new document, causing the process to not recognize objects in other environments.

Unfortunately, my report is a small portion of a much larger analysis, and the code would be too cumbersome to run completely from the Rmd file.

Solution: Knit and save your document from the command line.

```
rmarkdown::render("path/your_doc.Rmd")
```