# Save googleway output as html to host online

Tags: r, googleway

I am using the excellent `googleway` package for R, to plot my data as markers on a google map (hosted locally on my desktop). I would like to find some way to output this map to the web, so that I can view it from my iPhone/iOS device. Or better, to send it to the Google Maps app on my phone, so I can get directions to my markers, interactively.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this package make a HTML widget like leaflet? If that is the case, this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31642030/5028841

Comment: @JonGrub is right, that's how you save a Google Map widget. But note [this issue](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues/79) you may encounter if you don't have the correct pandoc installed. Or you can host it inside a shiny on shinyapps.io

Comment: @JonGrub Ah perfect! If you want to add this as an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks @SymbolixAU!

Comment: That's ok, I usually don't like to write answers if there is no reproducible code I can back up my answer with. Happy it helped.